# Latin Square Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I would like to create some latin square based problems similar to the ones in these images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But I'm lost about how to pick the "hint" numbers (those that are not hidden) so my problem has only one unique solution.

Is there a clear defined criteria to accomplish this?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatinSquare.html